# ff addon execute menu item

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I want to modify an existing addon for simplicity. I have this code:

```
<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
<menu id="llOpenLocalLink" label="&llOpenLocalLink.label;" insertbefore="context-sep-open" >

 <menupopup>
  <menuitem id="llOpenInThisTab" label="&llOpenInThisTab.label;" oncommand="LocalLink.openLinkInThisTab(event)"/>
  <menuitem id="llOpenInNewTab" label="&llOpenInNewTab.label;" oncommand="LocalLink.openLinkInNewTab(event)"/>
  <menuitem id="llOpenInNewWindow" label="&llOpenInNewWindow.label;" oncommand="LocalLink.openLinkInNewWindow(event)"/>
 </menupopup>

</menu>
</popup>
```

And I only want a single menu entry which is executed if clicked. I tried this but it is not executed:

```
<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
<menu id="llOpenLocalLink" label="&llOpenLocalLink.label;" insertbefore="context-  sep-open" oncommand="LocalLink.openLinkInNewTab(event)">
</menu>
</popup>
```

Ok. I found the answer:

```
<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
  <menuitem id="llOpenLocalLink" label="&llOpenLocalLink.label;" insertbefore="context-sep-open" oncommand="LocalLink.openLinkInNewTab(event)"/>
</popup>
```